# Generating random integer that never repeat for database id's

Tags: android, random, integer, int

I am currently generating id's based on the adapters count. Using androrm an "object relational mapper especially for android," to organize the database.  I would like to generate random numbers that never repeat's as the new id. Using random generated integers that never repeats would allow me to reference that id with another data set organized by that id.  The count() method interferes with the other data set if an item is deleted.  How would I generate random numbers that never repeat?

```
public boolean save() {

    int id = FoodLog.objects(context(), FoodLog.class).all().count() + 1;
    return this.save(context(), id);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply do that as far as i know, but if you want unique numbers all the time why don't you fetch the timestamp? like this:

```
long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: I had to format the date because an integer is 32 bit and can only be 10 places in length.  The data set also calls for an int not a long that is why I did that. Thanks for you answer it solved my issue!

Comment: yeah i know it's not random, but the requirement of OP was to generate unique numbers, random or not. :)